# Regex issue to validate number must not come after dash and it should not contain ip address

Tags: regex

I want regex with alphanumeric and (.-) with some condition.

1. number should not come after - character
2. It should not accept ip address.
3. (.-) should not come at the beginning and at the end but it can come in between.

For ex:

```
abc-123 // invalid
abcxyz // valid
abc-xyz // valid
-abc // invalid
abc- // invalid
.abc // invalid
abc. // invalid
```

https://regex101.com/r/PgLFkq/3

Thanks!

Comment: You might try `^(?!.*(?:-\d|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}))[a-z\d]+(?:[. -]+[a-z\d]+)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PgLFkq/4)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be using a negative lookahead after matching a hyphen `-(?![0-9])` to check it is not followed by digit.

To not match an ip address, you could use a negative lookahead to check that it does not match a pattern like `^(?![0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$)`

```
^(?![0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:\.|-(?![0-9]))[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, check what is directly to the right it not

  - `[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$` Match an ip like format
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a-z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\.|-(?![0-9]))` Match either `.` or `-` not followed by a digit
  - `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a-z0-9 so it can not and on `.` or `-`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwpLr5/1)